# How to know if an article from Wikipedia XML Dump is a List?

Tags: xml, wikipedia, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-templates, wikimedia-dumps

There are  directives for telling whether an article is a Disambiguation page.
I would like to know if there is any directive/Wikimedia Template used to flag an article as a list?

So far the only way I've found to check this is via Wikidata's [P360 Property](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P360), but Ideally I would like to get this information from the Wikipedia XML dump.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you look at subcategories of [Category:Lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists), but it seems that contains *a lot* of junk. So, maybe filtering just by the article name could work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such information in the article, but you can check the title if it start with *"[List of...](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=default&search=%22List%20of%20%22&fulltext=Search)"*.

I'm not sure that all items which have Property:P360 are list articles (for example some disambiguation items like [Q3086](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3086)), but you can [access them](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3AWhatLinksHere&limit=500&target=Property%3AP360&namespace=0) by [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bbacklinks):

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=backlinks&bltitle=Property:P360&blnamespace=0&bllimit=500
```

All list articles are marked in Wikidata by [instance of](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31) Wikimedia list article ([Q13406463](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q13406463)). You can get all them by using [WikidataQuery API](http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html):

```
http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[31:13406463]
```

Currently they are 216,685 ([104,843 in enwiki](http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[31:13406463]%20AND%20link[enwiki]))

You can also filter all items with P360 which are not disambiguation items:

```
http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[360] AND noclaim[31:4167410]
```